# BIG O In absence of enough information

Tags: performance, time-complexity, big-o

So, lets say you have a function, `X(N)` that is a total black box. You don't know the growth rate of the function, you can't look it up, and you can't view the source (at the moment).

Next lets examine it in the context of another function

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    X(N);
```

The code that you wrote is linear, yet clearly the function `X` has an impact of the growth rate of *your* function. 
If, for example, `X(N)` expands into `for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)` your function is quadratic.

**My question is this:** If someone is asking what the Big O of your function is, what is the best way to describe the growth rate of your function?

I said I would call this linear, and the defense of my answer is the following.

If you knew the actual growth rate of `X`, you can give an accurate estimation of your code, yet while you can (in one way or another) get the code eventually, most functions don't come with performance statistics.

So if you did get access to the code of `X`, you could include it in your estimation, but where do you draw the line? `X` likely also calls other functions, which then call other functions. I feel that outside of manufactured  scenarios where you are dealing with perfectly compartmentalized code, if you don't already know the growth rates of the black box functions being called you have to decide to estimate the code that you can.

Comment: What's the problem with `O(N*o(X))` for an upper-bound test!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would talk about drawing the line, I'd simply like to deliver like :-

The code's complexity :- `O(N*o(X))`

As soon as one get's to judge the complexity of the function X(N), one can simply substitute in the formula.

Till then, it will be a shorthand but useful notation all in all along with satisfying the loop's complexity.

Comment: I don't think `o(X)` is a common notation when `X` is a function.

Comment: It might not be the proper notation, but I think it's pretty clear in its intent in this situation.

Comment: Well, @cfh-Thanks for commenting! But, o(X) will give a more precise evaluation of complexity,it is perfectly acceptable in this case.Whenever you need to substitute,it can easily be replaced---just talking about more tighter constant factor.

Comment: I think I agree with @Phylogenesis . It makes the intention clear. Thanks suman.

Comment: @Taekahn-You are most welcome. Thanks and keep posting so that we along with you could be benefitted :)

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't tell. There just isn't enough information. Saying that your function is linear is wrong unless `X(N)` is constant time.

You could, however, measure the time that `X(N)` takes to complete for different input sizes. Often this will give you a rough estimate of how it behaves asymptotically.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is a very good question. People generally forget a crucial step: **Identifying the *basic operation***.

### Theoretical Analysis of Time Efficiency

Time efficiency is analyzed by determining the number of repetitions of the *basic operation* as a function of input size.

***Basic operation***: The operation that contributes most towards the running time of the algorithm.

We try to select things as *basic operation* which can be executed by in O(1) time, or close to that, actually what we select is often sub-linear operations. For example:

- Assigning a value to a variable
- Looking up the value of a particular element in an array
- Comparing two values
- Incrementing a value
- Basic arithmetic operations such as addition and multiplication

Basic arithmetic operations for example obviously not O(1). See this question from computer science: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time

So, we approximate O(1) when deciding on a *basic operation*.

Let *C(n)* be the number of times basic operation needs to be executed. And let *execTime* be the execution time of *basic operation* on a particular computer.

Then we can estimate the running time *T(n)* of an algorithm by:

```
T(n) ≈ execTime * C(n)
```

As you can see, efficiency class (Big-O for example) only depends on *C(n)*, as *execTime* will be constant anyway (and we don't care constants in asymptotic analysis). So, the task is to find *C(n)*.

### Analysis of Your Code

First we decide on *input parameter*, which is obviously *N*.

Then we decide on *basic operation*, and this is the part makes the difference.

If we decide on *X(N);* as *basic operation*, then:

```
T(N) ≈ execTime * C(N)
C(N) = N
O(execTime * N) = O(n)
```

If we would know what's happening inside *X(N)*, we could decide on a *basic operation* which occurs *N* times in each *X(N)* operation for example, then:

```
T(N) ≈ execTime * C(N)
C(N) = N * N
O(execTime * N * N) = O(N * N) = O(n^2)
```

We could also select the whole loop as the *basic operation*:

```
T(N) ≈ execTime * C(N)
C(N) = 1
O(execTime * 1) = O(1)
```

So which one is correct? All of them. Which one makes sense? It all depends what comparison you want to do.

For example, when comparing performance of sorting algorithms, *basic operations* are *key comparisons*, because the most significant work in a sorting algorithm is comparing keys, and all sorting algorithms do key comparison, so this way, we can compare them each other.

To conclude, you can select *X(N)* as *basic operation* and say the algorithmic complexity is *O(N)*. *X(N)* doesn't have to be O(1) strictly, as I explained above, we already neglect basic operations with greater complexity than O(1). What's actually important here is what comparison you want to do.

Let's think that you want to compare these two algorithms.

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    X(N);
```

and

```
for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        X(N);
```

Here, if you select *X(N)* as *basic operation* for both, you would compare apples with apples, you would assess *O(N)* vs *O(N^2)* and it would be **perfectly** fine.

If you feel it's wrong because *X(N)* is not *O(1)*, consider this one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    System.out.print(N);
```

A simple print method from Java. We select it as a *basic operation* without thinking at all, as *it's just a print statement*, and assume it's *O(1)*. But it's not. It's complexity is sub-linear, but definitely not constant. Time it takes to print grows as the size of the print item(*N* in this case) grows.

So, *X(N)* or *System.out.println(N)*, does it matter?

P.S. I didn't invent the approximation technique above. I did prepare the answer using [this](ftp://doc.nit.ac.ir/cee/jazayeri/Algorithms/Books/Design%20&%20Analysis%20of%20Algorithm.pdf) book, mostly chapter two. I recommend you to take a look.

Comment: This is not really true; I believe you are mixing up _time efficiency_ and _time complexity_, the latter which we describe using the tools of asymptotic analysis. In you first example, you describe that _"deciding on `X(N)` to be a `basic operation`"_ can be used to infer that the Big-O lower bound of the algorithms asymptotic behaviour is `O(N)` (I assume `n` is a typo here). However, if we're analyzing the behaviour of our algorithm with regard to `N`, this statement is similar to saying _"if we decide on X(N)=N"_. This doesn't really make sense in this context, as `X(N)` is unknown. ...

Comment: ... So to sum up, as long as `X(N)` is unknown, we can't really say anything regarding the asymptotic behaviour of our algorithm, at least no more specific than in terms of the unknown `X(N)`. Recall that our input parameter is `N`; hence the _"basic operator"_ should reflect the growth of the algorithm with increased `N`. We can never derive a bound `O(N)` without knowing the value of `X(N)`. Other than this however, I believe you are making some good points.

Comment: I prepared the answer using *Introduction to Design and Analysis of Algorithms* 3rd edition, chapter 2, I recommend you to have a look. I'm quite confident that this info is correct.

Comment: It doesn't matter if a code block is known or unknown, it all depends of your basic operation decision.

Comment: Perhaps in the context of your book, but not here. As we are studying the algorithms asymptotic behaviour w.r.t. to `N`, we can _never_ say that the algorithm has an upper asymptotic bound described as `O(N)`, not without knowing `X(N)`. This is especially true if we go back to the core case of asymptotic analysis of _functions_, rather than algorithms. If we use your approach above, then we could infer that the asymptotic behaviour of _any_ function or algorithm with regard to growing `N` is `O(N)`, simply by choosing to wrap any complexity whatsoever within a _"basic operator"_.

Comment: The use and mention of a _"basic operator"_ is appropriate, but there must be some constraint as to what a basic operator is; and in this context, we cannot define an unknown function of `N` to be a basic operator. I'd be surprised if the author of your reference encourage such analysis tricks.

Comment: The method I explained above is not applicable to pure asymptotic analysis theory. We select a basic operation and neglect others to simplify approximation. As you can see, I used an approximation sign, and an equal sign. If the case would be maths, then you would be right, but it's computer science and we do approximations.

Comment: Anyway, as I said before, I didn't invent this method, you can check the book, which is a quite famous book for teaching computer science in universities.

Comment: OK, let me give you the link to the book then: ftp://doc.nit.ac.ir/cee/jazayeri/Algorithms/Books/Design%20&%20Analysis%20of%20Algorithm.pdf

Comment: My sole objection in this discussion has been the use of Big-O notation in combination with the asymptotic analysis method you describe (note that I wrote that other than this, you are making some good points). _If_ we are to use Big-O notation to describe the asymptotic behaviour of an algorithm or function, _with regard to growth of a quantity of N_, then we cannot join the theory above with Big-O notation and simply wrap an unknown function `X(N)`, of _unknown growth_, under the pretext of being a _basic operator_.

Comment: (And being a function or an algorithm, we can never _"approximate"_ the asymptotic behaviour of O(N*X(N)) as O(N) just by choosing the _unknown quantity of `X(N)`_ as our _"basic operator"_. There is no difference here between "maths" and "computer science")

Comment: From the book, page 44 *"... One possible approach is to count the number of times each of the algorithm’s
operations is executed. This approach is both excessively difficult and, as we
shall see, usually unnecessary. The thing to do is to identify the most important
operation of the algorithm, called the basic operation, the operation contributing
the most to the total running time, and compute the number of times the basic
operation is executed. ..."*

Comment: Again, this is _one method_ of complexity analysis, and again, you _cannot join this with Big-O notation_ for a given quantity `N` in the sense you are trying to do above: by defining an _unknown function of `N`_, `X(N)`, as a basic operator. You should leave that chapter of your book (describing, I assume, a perfectly sound way of analyzing complexity of algorithms) and read up on the definition of Big-O notation, see e.g. https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation

Comment: Almost every program runs external code, from a library, which we don't know what's happening inside. We make operations, which we don't know underlying implementations, so complexities. We simply neglect them while approximating complexity.

Comment: Big O depends *f(n)*, *f(n)* in my calculation is *T(n)*, and *T(n)* depends *C(n)*. So result of Big O varies depending on *C(n)*. Do we agree on this? And *C(n)* is number of times basic op is executed, by definition. And we can select anything as a basic op (of course we should do a sensible choice).

Comment: These will be my final comments here, pardon for this, but I just don't have the time. I simply don't agree with you on this (agree to disagree?). Anyway, lets say we study asymptotic behaviour of, say, `f(n)`, _w.r.t. growth of `n`_, and we can infer that `f(n)` will grow according to `n * X(n)`, with `X(n)` unknown. From this, we can never reach the conclusion that `f(n)` is in `O(n)`, since defining `X(n)` as a basic operator (when it apparently is a _function of our parameter of study, `n`_) without knowing it's content will break the definition and use of Big-O notation. <next>

Comment: _If_ `X(n)`, were in fact, some function `X(m)` (a function of another parameter than the one we are studying!), then sure, we could define `X(m)` as a basic operation _with regard to `n`_. However, with `X(n)` being a function of `n`, we cannot wrap it up as a "basic operator" in _our Big-O analysis of complexity of `f(n)` w.r.t. growth of `n`_.

Comment: OK, thanks for constructive comments. Your last comment made me suspicious about this, perhaps you are right, it's clear on X(m), but suspicious on X(n). I'm going to ask this to a professor and share the answer here.

Comment: I talked with my professor, and expanded the answer. Please tell if something is missing.

Comment: You answer shows great effort, and it's a nice edit, and I'll admin I'm now a bit unsettled on this question. I still don't quite agree (note: I'm much less qualified than, say, your professor on this subject) that we can, _in the context of Big-O_, freely choose unknown `X(N)` as a basic operator (when we studying _algorithmic growth of N_), and e.g. say that your two examples above can be assessed as in `O(N)` and `O(N^2)`. We could, however, define a function `Y(N)` such at `X(N) ∈ = O(Y(N))` holds, and say that your two examples are in `O(N·Y(N))` and `O(N^2·Y(N))`, respectively.

Comment: ... The link to cs.stackexchange contains a great answer, but also here the discussion covers _known_  basic operations that run in (most of the cases) `O(1)` or grows w.r.t. an entity that is not depending on `N`. As I wrote previously, choosing a basic operator `X(M)` when studying asymptotic growth of `N` (w.r.t. Big-O notation) is totally ok, but when the unknown chosen as basic operator depends (in an unknown way) upon `N`, I'm dubious. Anyway, lets leave this, I come from mathematics and perhaps I'm too coloured by how Big-O is used when analyzing functions rather than algorithms. ...

Comment: You are right but, saying `O(N.Y(N))` would not be a solution, it's not a time complexity class, it's an unsolved equation. The point here is, approximation and the comparison you want to make. All Big-O thing is just an approximation at all.

Comment: ... I think we can agree, however, that there is more value in using a more rigorous notation when studying your two examples above, e.g., let `Y(N)` be a function such at `X(N) ∈ = O(Y(N))` holds ... , functions run in `O(N·Y(N))` and `O(N^2·Y(N))`, respectively. Writing that the functions run in `O(N)` and `O(N^2)`, respectively, _will_ confuse many readers of such a statement, even if it's explicitly stated that one has chosen _the unknown_ `X(N)` as the basic operators. And as for all statements intended for use by other developers and so on, we want to avoid possible misinterpretations.

Comment: If you believe that my notation is inferior, you can edit my notation, and I would really appreciate it. I come from CS, and I'm not that fluent on math notations :-)

Comment: Absolutely not _inferior_! We're simply discussing here, and I'm no expert (as I wrote, after your edit I'm unsettled on the subject), so I'll think you can leave you text as is. The discussion here in the comments can perhaps be of value to someone (or for someone more knowledge to nudge on on). I think I'll just wrap up as: possibly (I'm unsure) it's theoretically sound to use the approach in your answer above, but I wouldn't recommend it it practice, as it's quite open for the misinterpretation (i.e. that the algorithm being described runs in `O(N^2)`). Now, happy algorithms' analysing!

Comment: Thank you for your constructive criticism too!

Comment: Thank you also, for this discussion.